# One of my activity is crashing on emulator

Tags: java, android, emulation

```
This is my first question please bear with me.
I am trying to drawing over other app 
my code is working fine on Mobile but when i am trying to run this app on emulator my app get crash when i click on button.
actually i am intenting from Main activty with itemclick listner 


package com.shahabtech.ytbooster;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
    public class Popup2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        private WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private View mView;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private  Context context;
        private WindowManager mWindowManager;
        int UserCoins2 = 0;
        ArrayList<model>List;
        SelectListner selectListner;
        int Reward;
        int Views;
        String YT_ID;
        String UID;
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup2);
    
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this));
            UID = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    
            getCoins();
    
            String yT_LINK = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LINK");
            Reward = getIntent().getIntExtra("WATCHTIME",0);
            Views = getIntent().getIntExtra("VIEWS",0);
            YT_ID = getYouTubeId(yT_LINK);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                // set the layout parameters of the window
                mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        // Shrink the window to wrap the content rather
                        // than filling the screen
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        // Display it on top of other application windows
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                        // Don't let it grab the input focus
    //                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    
            }
            // getting a LayoutInflater
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) Popup2.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // inflating the view with the custom layout we created
            mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_popup2, null);
    
            getCoins();
            MycountDown mycountDown = new MycountDown(Reward*1000,1000);
            mycountDown.start();
    
    
            TextView TvRecord  =mView.findViewById(R.id.reward_2);
            TextView TV_Views = mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_announsment);
    //        TextView TV_PlayTime = mView.findViewById(R.id.play_time2);
            TV_Views.setText(String.valueOf(Views));
            TvRecord.setText(String.valueOf(Reward));
    //        TV_PlayTime.setText(String.valueOf(Reward)+" Seconds");
    //        Tv_Coins.setText(String.valueOf(UserCoins2));
            mView.findViewById(R.id.stop_watch2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Popup2.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mycountDown.cancel();
                    close2(Popup2.this);
                }
            });
    
            mParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager)Popup2.this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    
            Open(Popup2.this);
    //        Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Link is "+UserCoins2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            openYoutube();
    
        }
    
        public void Open(Context context) {
    
            try {
                getCoins();
                if(mView.getWindowToken()==null) {
                    if(mView.getParent()==null) {
                        mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams);
    //                    Toast.makeText(context, "Opend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error1",e.toString());
            }
    
        }
    
        public void close2(Context context) {
    
            try {
    
                ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
    
                mView.invalidate();
    
                ((ViewGroup)mView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error2",e.toString());
            }
        }
    
        private void openYoutube(){
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+YT_ID));
            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+YT_ID));
            try {
              Popup2.this.startActivity(appIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    //            Popup2.this.startActivity(webIntent);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Install YouTube First "+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    
        private void openYoutube2(){
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"));
            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="));
            try {
                Popup2.this.startActivity(appIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    //            Popup2.this.startActivity(webIntent);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Install YouTube First "+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    
        private void getCoins(){
            String UID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
           DatabaseReference reference;
           reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS_DATA");
           reference.child(UID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()){
                       if (task.getResult().exists()){
    //                       Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Successfully found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                           UserCoins2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("coins").getValue()));
                           TextView TV_Coins = mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_coins2);
                          TV_Coins.setText(String.valueOf(UserCoins2));
    //                       Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "User Coins are "+UserCoins2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }else {
                           Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }else {
                       Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Data Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });
        }
    
        public String getYouTubeId(String youTubeUrl) {
            String pattern = "(?<=youtu.be/|watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*";
            Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(youTubeUrl);
            if (matcher.find()) {
    
                return matcher.group();
            } else {
    
                return "error";
            }
        }
        public class MycountDown extends CountDownTimer{
    
            public MycountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
    
                TextView TV_PlayTime = mView.findViewById(R.id.play_time2);
                TV_PlayTime.setText(String.valueOf(l/1000+" Seconds"));
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
    
                update_coins();
                update_views();
                close2(Popup2.this);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Popup2.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
    
            }
        }
    
        private void update_coins() {
    
            UserCoins2 = UserCoins2 + Reward;
    
            HashMap Update_coins = new HashMap();
            Update_coins.put("coins", UserCoins2);
            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS_DATA");
            databaseReference.child(UID).updateChildren(Update_coins).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Reward Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Coins Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        private void update_views() {
    
            Views = Views + 1;
    
            HashMap Update_Views = new HashMap();
            Update_Views.put("V_COMPLETED", Views);
            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LINKS").child("LINK");
            databaseReference.child(YT_ID).updateChildren(Update_Views).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    //                    Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Views Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Popup2.this, "Views Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    
    
    // My XML is as follow
    
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="0dp"
    
        >
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/material_dynamic_neutral80"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Coins"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_coins2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout293"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView28"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Play Time"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/play_time2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout293"
                android:layout_width="404dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">
    
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout23"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView62"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Reward"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reward_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="00"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout293">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Announcment"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_announsment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Coming Soon"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3">
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/window_close"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Skip Video"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/stop_watch2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Stop Watching"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

//Here is my logcat
```

Sir here is my logcat when i trying to run my android 11 app running smoothly but on lower version of android and also on emulator app got crash when i click on recyclerview item view.
i try to changed my layout and comment out all code of pop2 activity then not crashing.
actually in my pop2 activty i am inflating a view and also setting content view

```
2022-09-11 11:59:55.342 3279-3327/com.shahabtech.ytbooster D/EGL_adreno: eglGetConfigAttrib: bad attrib 0x3339
2022-09-11 11:59:55.342 3279-3327/com.shahabtech.ytbooster E/EGL_adreno: tid 3327: eglGetConfigAttrib(1207): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2022-09-11 11:59:55.377 3279-3327/com.shahabtech.ytbooster E/EGL_adreno: [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
2022-09-11 11:59:55.377 3279-3327/com.shahabtech.ytbooster D/EGL_adreno: eglGetConfigAttrib: bad attrib 0x3339
2022-09-11 11:59:55.377 3279-3327/com.shahabtech.ytbooster E/EGL_adreno: tid 3327: eglGetConfigAttrib(1207): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2022-09-11 12:00:23.134 3279-3279/com.shahabtech.ytbooster W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@b8b0d00
2022-09-11 12:00:23.164 3279-3279/com.shahabtech.ytbooster D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-09-11 12:00:23.166 3279-3279/com.shahabtech.ytbooster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shahabtech.ytbooster, PID: 3279
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shahabtech.ytbooster/com.shahabtech.ytbooster.Popup2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.shahabtech.ytbooster.Popup2.onCreate(Popup2.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7197)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7188)
```

Comment: Please share the logcat logs

Comment: I have try to comment out my all code of  2nd activity but still activity was getting crash. But when i also Comment out   setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup2); amazingly activity not crashed even i have setContent Layout replace with others layout .

Comment: Umm so you fixed it?

Comment: still i can not fix

Comment: share the logcat window output

Comment: i am trying to add logcat but no luck

Comment: without logcat I am not sure what exactly is the problem

Comment: i have added logcat sir

Answer (score -1):

Thanks every one i have solved my problem after removing 1st constrain layout of my popup2 xml.